# Show Google Map in Material Dialog Android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to show google map in to a custom dialogue.. But i can not access SupportFragmentManager from dialogue class...

Here is my code....

```
public class AddressViewDialog extends MaterialDialog.Builder implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private MaterialDialog reviewDialog;
private double latitude = 23.0;
private double longitude = 90.0;
private SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;
private GoogleMap mMap;

public AddressViewDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);

    this.context = context;
    initializeView();
}

public void initializeView() {

    reviewDialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(this.getContext())
            .title(R.string.request_to_introduce)
            .customView(R.layout.dialog_pending_introducer_review, true)
            .show();

    View v = reviewDialog.getCustomView();

    mMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
    mMapFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);

    if (latitude != 0.0 && longitude != 0.0) {
        mMapFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    } else
        mMapFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    LatLng currentLoc = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLoc).title("My Location"));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLoc, 14.0f));
}
```

}

Here is my xml..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

It shows error in this line:
mMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);

I also Tried :
mMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);

Comment: Use the `DialogFragment`, it has dialog layout with `fragment`-like implementation

Answer (score 0):

You should call `getSupportFragmentManager()` not on `MaterialDialog.Builder` object (your `AddressViewDialog` extends `MaterialDialog.Builder`) but on `AppCompatActivity` object. So use

```
mMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) ((AppCompatActivity) this.context).getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
```

instead of

```
mMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
```

and create your `AddressViewDialog` from `MainActivity` this way:

```
new AddressViewDialog(MainActivity.this).show();
```

(`MainActivity` should extends `AppCompatActivity`).